# Remove IBAction UIButton Border

Tags: uibutton, border

I am very new to XCode and objective-c and need some help with removing the border from a UIButton.

my code is

```
- (IBAction)A0:(UIButton *)sender
{
     UIButton *enableButton = (UIButton *)sender;
     enableButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

I am trying to remove the border so its a clear button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove button border:

```
enableButton.buttonType = UIButtonTypeCustom;
```

Comment: This pointed me to the custom GUI option on the button properties in XCode. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hide border with following code 
for this you have to import **quartzcore.framework**

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
```